# XOR Tensorflow Non-convergence

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Here's a simple Tensorflow implementation of XOR.

Any idea why when TF random seed is 0, this does not converge and when it is not, it does? How can I make it converge without changing the network architecture (ie, keep hidden layer as Dense(2)) and keeping random seed = 0? TIA!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (
    Dense,
    Input,
)

tf.random.set_seed(0) # to reproduce non-convergence
# tf.random.set_seed(1234) # to converges

# XOR
X = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]], "float32")
Y = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]], "float32")

x = Input(shape=(2,))
y = Dense(2, activation="sigmoid")(x)
y = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(y)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error")

class logger(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch % 1000 == 0:
            print("epoch=", epoch, "loss=%.3f" % logs["loss"])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=20000, verbose=0, callbacks=[logger()])
```

Output when random seed = 0:

```
epoch= 0 loss=0.255
epoch= 1000 loss=0.235
epoch= 2000 loss=0.190
epoch= 3000 loss=0.154
epoch= 4000 loss=0.137
epoch= 5000 loss=0.130
epoch= 6000 loss=0.127
epoch= 7000 loss=0.126
epoch= 8000 loss=0.125
epoch= 9000 loss=0.125
epoch= 10000 loss=0.125
epoch= 11000 loss=0.125
epoch= 12000 loss=0.125
epoch= 13000 loss=0.125
epoch= 14000 loss=0.125
epoch= 15000 loss=0.125
epoch= 16000 loss=0.125
epoch= 17000 loss=0.125
epoch= 18000 loss=0.125
epoch= 19000 loss=0.125
```

Output when random seed = 1234:

```
epoch= 0 loss=0.275
epoch= 1000 loss=0.234
epoch= 2000 loss=0.186
epoch= 3000 loss=0.118
epoch= 4000 loss=0.059
epoch= 5000 loss=0.024
epoch= 6000 loss=0.008
epoch= 7000 loss=0.003
epoch= 8000 loss=0.001
epoch= 9000 loss=0.000
epoch= 10000 loss=0.000
epoch= 11000 loss=0.000
epoch= 12000 loss=0.000
epoch= 13000 loss=0.000
epoch= 14000 loss=0.000
epoch= 15000 loss=0.000
epoch= 16000 loss=0.000
epoch= 17000 loss=0.000
epoch= 18000 loss=0.000
epoch= 19000 loss=0.000
```

Comment: You have probably hit a local minima. Changing the learning rate of your optimizer might help. It's bad luck on how the weights of the network were initialized.

Comment: Hi Lescurel, I think you’re right! According to this (https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/131318) if we use a cross entropy loss function, the loss shape will be convex and we will only have a global minimum but I tried a few TF cross entropy loss still no luck...

Comment: From that page: if we use the cross-entropy loss it will be convex and gradient descent can easily converge to global minima

Comment: That is not true anymore if you have a hidden layer. See this post on the data science stack exchange for more in depth explanation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144378/is-cross-entropy-cost-function-for-neural-network-convex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default (since you haven't specified it), the optimizer is `"rmsprop"`, and it seems like it's not performing well for this task. The reason for that is: I have no idea. But if you use `"sgd"` with `"tanh"` activation for hidden layers, it will work:

```
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer='sgd')
```

```
epoch= 0 loss=0.425
epoch= 1000 loss=0.213
epoch= 2000 loss=0.182
epoch= 3000 loss=0.160
epoch= 4000 loss=0.130
epoch= 5000 loss=0.063
epoch= 6000 loss=0.023
epoch= 7000 loss=0.010
epoch= 8000 loss=0.006
epoch= 9000 loss=0.004
```

You can also try setting up the weights manually ;)

```
step_activation = lambda x: tf.cast(tf.greater_equal(x, 0.5), tf.float32)

x = Input(shape=(2,))
y = Dense(2, activation=step_activation)(x)
y = Dense(1, activation=step_activation)(y)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y, trainable=False)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error")

weights = [np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]]),
           np.array([-1.5, -0.5]),
           np.array([[-1], [1]]),
           np.array([-0.5])]


model.set_weights(weights)

model.evaluate(X, Y)
```

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
```

Copy/pastable:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.random.set_seed(0)

X = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
Y = [[0], [1], [1], [0]]

x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="tanh")(x)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="tanh")(y)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer='sgd')

history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=5000)
```

```
Epoch 5000/5000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 998us/step - loss: 0.0630
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas! Thank you for your reply. I did try your advice to change the optimizer to SGD but it's still not converging for me... (Tensorflow 2.4.1)

Comment: Forgot to say, you need to use tanh activation for hidden layers

Comment: SGD with a high enough learning rate (say 0.5) converges (although quite slowly), with a sigmoid activation function.